# Linux - Setting up a multi-user and multi-machine system where anyone can log to their user from any machine

Tags: linux, ansible, multiple-users

I Have the following setup:
Many computers (all of them have the latest Ubuntu), and more users than computers. I would like to make it so anyone can log to their user from any computer, and they have all their files, binaries, etc.

Plus, all of the computers would be controlled from a single computer running ansible.

My question is: How would I go about making it so that "anyone can log to their user from any computer, and they have all their files, binaries, etc."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> anyone can log to their user from any computer,

The first step is to actually have everyone's accounts on every computer.

You could in theory use Ansible to create identical accounts everywhere, but it's more common to put them on a central database, typically LDAP (using FreeIPA, or MS Active Directory, or a homegrown setup); in the past it was NIS but that's mostly gone out of fashion now. Ubuntu has two LDAP clients: SSSD (libnss_sss) and nslcd aka nss-pam-ldapd (libnss_ldap).

Second, since those accounts are meant for local login – with *passwords* rather than SSH keys – you'll want some kind of central authentication (which on Linux is a separate thing from the account database). Especially for Ansible-deployed accounts, you really don't want people to change their passwords locally on each machine and forget which machine had which password, so it's better to reroute `passwd` to talk to the central server.

For example, when using LDAP for accounts, it's common to let the same LDAP server handle authentication as well. However, in your situation, there are specific advantages in using Kerberos for authentication instead – which comes built-in with both AD and FreeIPA, but is easy to set up manually as well. The SSSD client will handle either LDAP or Kerberos via the same pam_sss; for everything else use pam_krb5.

> and they have all their files, binaries, etc.

Set up an NFSv4 server and put everyone's home directories on NFS. (And make sure both the network and the NFS server are fast enough to support that. Have a spare server available if the first one dies, otherwise *everyone's* work will come to a halt. Do backups.)

This could be done by just mounting the "all user homes" NFS share via fstab, but it's more common to use the *autofs* daemon which could mount individual home directories on demand.

You will definitely want to implement Kerberos for user authentication (e.g. via pam_krb5 or pam_sss), as this is the only way to have secure NFS access from untrusted client machines (using the `sec=krb5` mount option).

Comment: Thank you so much for all the tips! A couple of people have recommended "Kerberos". Is it difficult to set up?

Comment: Not really; I'd say running a standalone KDC (using MIT Krb5 or Heimdal) is about on the same level as e.g. DNS server using BIND (and a bit easier than LDAP or SMTP/IMAP servers), there really isn't much going on. Though you might prefer FreeIPA which integrates the whole user management system (Kerberos _and_ LDAP, and a web GUI, and other stuff, a bit like MS AD). AD itself always has Kerberos built in, too.

Comment: Usually it's the NFS setup that is the most finicky (both for Kerberos and in general), so once you have a KDC, I would actually suggest setting up Kerberos auth _for SSH_ first (I don't mean pam_krb5, I mean the 'GSSAPIAuthentication' mode) – once you have that working, proceed with NFS.

Comment: Oooh, FreeIPA sounds very interesting. I'll give it a go.

Thanks!

Comment: @PeterPetigru: As a side note, if you're reading an "NFS + FreeIPA" tutorial that says older kernels only support DES for Kerberos – ignore that part and continue with AES as default. (When it says "older" it's referring to kernels <2.6.35, which are more than 12 years old by now – all modern systems support AES and many don't even support DES anymore, but nobody has updated that tutorial since.)